# How do I make my local host display data?

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, backend, web-development-server

My local host has refused to load the ejs page even after trying several times and after changing the port from 3000 to 8080. It only keeps loading and sometimes displays 'This page can't be reached'.
Here's the code.

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const {v4:uuidv4} = require('uuid')

const router = require('./router')

const app = express()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
// const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.use(bodyparser.json)
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//Load static assets
app.use('/static',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')))
app.use('/assets',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public/assets')))

app.use(session({
               secret: uuidv4(),
               resave: false,
               saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use('/route', router)

//Home route
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
                res.render('base',{title: 'Login System'})
})


app.listen(PORT,()=>{
               console.log(`listening to request on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: I'm guessing you might be getting intermittant "port in use" errors trying to restart your app.  SUGGESTIONS: 1)hard-code the port# (for troubleshooting purposes): `const PORT = 8080;` 2) Check if there's currently a listener (before you restart your app): `netstat -an` (windows, look for "LISTENER" on port 8080), 3) kill the listener if you find one (e.g. Windows Task Mgr).  Please report back what you find.

Comment: You need to call `json()` function of body-parser module like `app.use(bodyparser.json())` instead of `app.use(bodyparser.json)`

Comment: start by changing to:  `app.use(express.json()); app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))`